# Running an SQL query with filterexpressions from textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm currently running a query in an ASP.NET gridview that uses filters from textboxes. My current code looks like this:

```
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ERPW2MIGConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT TOP 1000000 * FROM DWH.AIXW2S_T6946_TRANS_IMS"
      FilterExpression= "C6946_TRANS_NUM LIKE '{0}' AND (C6946_PART_KEY LIKE '{1}' OR ALIGNED_PART_NUMBER LIKE '{1}' OR C1001_ENG_PART_NUMBER LIKE '{1}')  AND C6946_TRANS_DATE >= #{2}# AND C6946_TRANS_DATE <= #{3}#">

<FilterParameters> 
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox2" Name="TRANS_NUM" PropertyName="text" Type="String" DefaultValue="" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"/> 
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox3" Name="PART_KEY" PropertyName="text"  Type="string"  DefaultValue="" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"/>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox4" Name="TRANS_DATE" PropertyName="text"  Type="DateTime"  DefaultValue="" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"/>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox5" Name="TRANS_DATE2" PropertyName="text"  Type="DateTime"  DefaultValue="" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"/>
        </FilterParameters> 
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

What I wanted help with is this: is there a way to run my filters in the select command directly as a WHERE statement? My query takes forever to run and I don't know the exact way the filterexpressions come into effect (i.e. is the query run, then filtered, or does it run with the filters from the start?). Also, could someone suggest any way to optimize the query?

Thanks.

Comment: Not an answer to your exact question, but here's a tip - do all of your database querying on the server-side, using code in code-behind or classes, etc. Don't use these silly ASP.NET filters which you can use on your ASPX pages. They lead to a poor, coupled, design. I've had to work with code in the past that used them, and they were a real pain quite honestly. You'll find it much easier without them.

Comment: I've actually never done anything like this before, I'm not an IT guy. I don't think I'd be able to figure out how to do it in raw code.

Comment: Ahh that's a shame, I understand it's not a trivial thing to change. OK, I'll admit I don't know the answer to your question, but I just thought I'd throw in the tip for future reference :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `FilterParameters` use `SelectParameters`. Following is an example

```
SelectCommand="SELECT TOP 1000000 * FROM DWH.AIXW2S_T6946_TRANS_IMS 
               WHERE C6946_TRANS_NUM = @TRANS_NUM AND ...." 
<selectparameters>
   <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox2" 
        Name="TRANS_NUM" PropertyName="text" Type="String" DefaultValue="" 
        ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"/> 
   ...
</selectparameters>
```